# Como fazer para quando clicar em "enviar" alterar o texto final Formulário

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Quero que o resultado do conteúdo digitado no campo "Texto" saia automaticamente entre um texto pré definido dentro do campo "Pós Texto".

Ex: ao digitar `exemplo` no campo "Texto" e clicar em enviar, o resultado aparecer automaticamente em "Pós Texto" `Seu "exemplo" aqui` ou `<<<< exemplo >>>>` `<div>exemplo</div>`
No momentos está assim:
 
[image: No momento está assim]

Onde quero chegar:
[image: Final]

```
<script>
  function submitted() {
    formValue = document.getElementsByName("texto")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("texto")[1].setAttribute("value", formValue); // Copia
    return false;
  }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return submitted()"> 
  Texto:<br><input type="text" name="texto">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar"><br><br> 
  Pós texto:<br><input type="text" name="texto">
</form>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara, vc quer mostrar o resultado em outra página é isto?

Comment: Reformulei a pergunta

Comment: Mas se vc não quer enviar o form, pois está dando um return false, pq pegar as informações de um formulário?

Comment: formValue = "<div>"+(document.getElementsByName("texto")[0].value)+"</div>";

Comment: Oi amigo! Por que fica alternando a marcação de um resposta a outra?

Comment: Oi desculpe é que eu não tinha percebido que só dava pra aceitar 1 como resposta certa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você já consegue pegar o valor do primeiro `input`, aí é só concatenar a ele o que você deseja usando o sinal `+` (semelhante ao ponto `.` no PHP).

Mas você pode usar outra sintaxe e dispensar o uso do `setAttribute`:

```
document.getElementsByName("texto")[1].value = 'seu "'+formValue+'" aqui';
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function submitted() {
   formValue = document.getElementsByName("texto")[0].value;
   document.getElementsByName("texto")[1].value = 'seu "'+formValue+'" aqui';
   return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitted()"> 
  Texto:<br><input type="text" name="texto">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar"><br><br> 
  Pós texto:<br><input type="text" name="texto">
</form>
```

Adicionando valores de vários campos:

```js
function submitted() {
   var formValue0 = '<div>'+ document.getElementsByName("texto")[0].value +'</div>';
   var formValue1 = '<script>'+ document.getElementsByName("texto")[1].value +'<\/script>';
   var formValue2 = '<style>'+ document.getElementsByName("texto")[2].value +'</style>';
   document.getElementsByName("texto")[3].value = formValue0+formValue1+formValue2;
   return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitted()"> 
  Campo 1:<br><input type="text" name="texto"><br>
  Campo 2:<br><input type="text" name="texto"><br>
  Campo 3:<br><input type="text" name="texto"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar"><br><br> 
  Pós texto:<br><input type="text" name="texto">
</form>
```

Para concatenar a tag `</script>` dentro do código, é preciso escapar a barra de fechamento, senão o código vai interpretar como se você estivesse encerrando o script:

```
 ↓
<\/script>
```

Comment: Sim, basta vc pegar os campos pelo índice [1], [2], [3] no `document.getElementsByName("texto")[índice].value` e alterar como quiser.

Comment: Não use o campo de respostas para colocar dúvidas. Atualizei a minha resposta com outros campos.

Comment: Apenas é preciso fazer isso com <\/script> ou algum outro também? tipo </head> </body> etc..

Comment: Só no </script>

Comment: eu mudei o "Pos Texto" pra `<textarea name="texto" style="height:200px"></textarea>` como faço pra cada um ficar em uma linha separada?

Comment: `formValue0+'\n'+formValue1+'\n'+formValue2;`

Answer (score 0):

Vou publicar meu comentário como resposta, já adequando para `com outros campos` etc..

> Basta fazer uso de concatenação.

**Concatenação**
Podemos entender concatenação como sendo a junção de duas strings (frases ou palavras). O operador para fazer concatenação é o sinal de adição `+`.

```js
function submitted() {
   var formValue = '<div>'+ document.getElementsByName("texto")[0].value +'</div>';
   formValue += '<script>'+ document.getElementsByName("texto")[1].value +'<\/script>';
   formValue += '<style>'+ document.getElementsByName("texto")[2].value +'</style>';
   document.getElementsByName("texto")[3].value = formValue;
   return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitted()"> 
  Campo 1:<br><input type="text" name="texto"><br>
  Campo 2:<br><input type="text" name="texto"><br>
  Campo 3:<br><input type="text" name="texto"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar"><br><br> 
  Pós texto:<br><input type="text" name="texto">
</form>
```

Para `textarea`, para cada um ficar em uma linha separada, e para não enviar campos em branco ou nulos.

`linha separada`  basta acrescentar `\n` (nova linha) no local que quiser quebrar a linha.

`para não enviar campos em branco` utilize o método `trim()`

> O método trim() remove os espaços desnecessários declarados no início e/ou no final de uma string.

Compatibilidade entre navegadores

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
function submitted() { 
   
var texto0= (document.getElementsByName("texto")[0].value).trim();
 var texto1= (document.getElementsByName("texto")[1].value).trim();
  var texto2= (document.getElementsByName("texto")[2].value).trim();
   
   if(texto0!=""){
    texto0= '<div>'+ texto0 +'</div>\n';
   }
   if(texto1!=""){
   texto1= '<script>'+ texto1 +'<\/script>\n';
   }
   if(texto2!=""){
   texto2= '<span>'+ texto2 +'<\/span>\n';
   }

   var formValue = texto0 + texto1 + texto2;
   document.getElementsByName("texto")[3].value = formValue;
   return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitted()"> 
  Campo 1:<br><input type="text" name="texto"><br>
  Campo 2:<br><input type="text" name="texto"><br>
  Campo 3:<br><input type="text" name="texto"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar"><br><br> 
  <textarea name="texto" style="height:200px"></textarea
</form>
```

> Nas tags de fechamento `</script>` deve-se escapar a barra `/` com uma contrabarra `\`,ou seja  `<\/script>`
>
> também pode usar da seguinte forma: `</scr'+'ipt>`

```
formValue += '<script>'+ document.getElementsByName("texto")[1].value +'</scr'+'ipt>\n';
```

> quando divide em duas strings e concatena, fará com que não atrapalhe o motor de renderização

Comment: Se o campo tiver em branco ele vai enviar a string do mesmo jeito, como fazer para que ele n envie nada dos campos em branco?

Comment: @MarkVaaz, mas o que vc está enviando? Isto não está claro na sua pergunta nem no seu comentário. Todos os campos? Só o do Pós texto?

Comment: Na verdade eu não vou usar o formulario para enviar algo, só achei o formulario a maneira mais facil (na minha opinião) de fazer o que preciso, que é um gerador de HTML personalizável, geralmente eu preciso fazer algo que vai o msm codigo repetidamente, e com isso agr eu posso agilizar um processo q levava 10 minutos pra 2 minutos, e também simplificar o trabalho de uma maneira que até alguém que não sabe nada consiga fazer

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda